# Effect inside the return of a React.FC Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I created this site using React and I am facing the following problem:

I have a function that returns createElement creating a Card with the information of my store's products **(#1)**, for this to be displayed on the screen I make a map in the array that the backend returns to me by passing the createElement function **(#2(**SEE RETURN**))**, however, I want this map to happen whenever State where my backend response is stored change.

Can you help me?

CODES:

**The backend response is a JSON with the following interface**

```
interface RendererData {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   price: number;
   description: string;
   image: string;
}
```

**#1**

```
const renderer = useCallback((dados: RendererData) => {
return React.createElement(StyledCard, { key: dados.id }, [
  <Card key={dados.id}>
    <Card.Img src={`http://localhost:3333/${dados.image}`} />
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{dados.name}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>R$ {dados.price}</Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
    <Card.Footer>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Qtd." min="0" max="10" />
      <Button className="add-to-cart" variant="primary">
        ADICIONAR AO CARRINHO
        <FaCartPlus size={28} />
      </Button>
    </Card.Footer>
  </Card>,
]);
}, []);
```

**#2**

```
const GridProducts: React.FC = () => {
 const [test, setTest] = useState([]);


 useEffect(() => {
    async function getProducts() {
     api.get('/products').then(
      await function (response) {
       setTest(response.data);
       },
     );
    }
    getProducts();
  }, []);


 const renderer = useCallback((dados: RendererData) => {
   return React.createElement(StyledCard, { key: dados.id }, [
     <Card key={dados.id}>
       <Card.Img src={`http://localhost:3333/${dados.image}`} />
       <Card.Body>
         <Card.Title>{dados.name}</Card.Title>
         <Card.Text>R$ {dados.price}</Card.Text>
       </Card.Body>
       <Card.Footer>
         <input type="number" placeholder="Qtd." min="0" max="10" />
         <Button className="add-to-cart" variant="primary">
           ADICIONAR AO CARRINHO
           <FaCartPlus size={28} />
         </Button>
       </Card.Footer>
     </Card>,
   ]);
 }, []);

 return (
   <>
     <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
       <Container>{test.map(config => renderer(config))}</Container>
     </div>
   </>
 );
};
```

Comment: Would really suggest you take some time learning about promises and async/await. How they are used in your sample might work, but it also makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

i just added a callback with the map:

```
const display = useCallback(() => {
  return test.map(config => renderer(config));
}, [test]);
```

and changed the return:

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
   <Container >{display()}</Container>
</div>
```